# Why Florish animation in Animation Nodes doesn't work in this case？

Tags: animation-nodes

I tried Florish animation with AnimationNodes.
I tried two methods and one succeeded and the other didn't work.
But I don't know what makes this difference.
I think it's in how to use Object Instancer, but I wasn't sure.
I want to study for the future.
I'll attach a .blend file, so if you notice anything, could you please let me know?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Add more than just the Blend FIle. Like Screenshots of your nodes and your methods result

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I edited it.